# Using AttributeConverter converting to UUID results in 'No Dialect mapping for JDBC type' exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

So I have a class, lets say `Dog` (not an entity) containing only an `UUID` field. I then have the following `AttributeConverter`:

```java
@Converter
public class DogConverter implements AttributeConverter<Dog, UUID> {
    @Override
    public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(final Dog attribute) {
        return attribute.getUuid();
    }

    @Override
    public Dog convertToEntityAttribute(final UUID dbData) {
        return new Dog(dbData);
    }
}
```

I then use the `Dog` as a field in an entity class `DogHouse`:

```java
@Entity
class DogHouse {
    ...
    @Convert(converter = DogConverter.class)
    private Dog dog;
    ...
}
```

Then I use liquibase to create a diff changelog against an empty postgresql database which then results in the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 206384196
```

When I change to `DogConverter` to convert between a `Dog` and a `String` by also mapping the `UUID` to a string, liquibase works fine and no exception shows up.

Does anyone have any idea why the exception occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: Add `@Converter` to your `DogConverter.class`. Yet your setup looks like you would want a normal mapping using `@OneToOne`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer `@Converter` was already on the `DogConverter`, I forgot to include it in the example, I edited the example.

Comment: Show the configuration of your hibernate sessionFactory

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, also with UUID as the database type - did you find a solution or did you leave it as String?

Comment: @MitchKent I didn't find a solution, I left it as a String

Comment: Thanks for your reply pepijno, I also didn't find a solution so my workaround was to use a custom @Type

Comment: Another solution (arguably a hack) that requires almost no effort is to mark the Dog property in Doghouse, like so `@Embedded @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = Column(name = "dog_id")) private Dog dog;` where value is the UUID property name in Dog and dog_id is the UUID column in the DB referencing to the dog table. Optionally, the Dog class should have the `@Embeddable` annotation, but for me it worked even without.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with postgis Geometry and concluded that types supported by converter are limited compared to the ones supported by entity fields.
In this post https://gitter.im/hibernate/hibernate-orm?at=5ab11305e4d1c636041f1251 if you search for "dialect" you see a similar questions. Answer seems to be it's not possible with Hibernate 5.2. Maybe it will be possible with Hibernate 6.